# Advanced grouping in .csv file with python

Tags: python

I'm going to do a data analysis in a CSV file. The data consists of three columns: product title, product classification code and supplier name. The challenge is that company names are not unique. Consider, for example, a company and its subsidiaries, I want all these companies to be in the same category and under one general title. In addition, the product can be a joint product of two or more companies, the names of these companies are separated by ";" in the relevant column.Each company has several product codes, and the products are separated in the relevant column by ";".
I wrote the following code to categorize company names, but I need help writing the whole code.

```
for i in range(len(lstCompanyList)):
    if lstCompanyList[i] == 'ABU DHABI NATIONAL OIL COMPANY; ABU DHABI COMPANY FOR ONSHORE PETROLEUM OPERATION LIMITED':
        s=2
    for k in range(len(lstlstUniqeCompany)):
        if lstlstUniqeCompany[k][0].lower()+' ' in lstCompanyList[i].lower() or lstlstUniqeCompany[k][1].lower()+' ' in lstCompanyList[i].lower()\
                or lstlstUniqeCompany[k][0].lower()+';' in lstCompanyList[i].lower() or lstlstUniqeCompany[k][1].lower()+';' in lstCompanyList[i].lower()\
                or lstlstUniqeCompany[k][0].lower()+')' in lstCompanyList[i].lower() or lstlstUniqeCompany[k][1].lower()+')' in lstCompanyList[i].lower()\
                or lstlstUniqeCompany[k][0].lower()+',' in lstCompanyList[i].lower() or lstlstUniqeCompany[k][1].lower()+',' in lstCompanyList[i].lower()\
                or lstlstUniqeCompany[k][0].lower()+'-' in lstCompanyList[i].lower() or lstlstUniqeCompany[k][1].lower()+'-' in lstCompanyList[i].lower()\
                or lstlstUniqeCompany[k][0].lower()+'.' in lstCompanyList[i].lower() or lstlstUniqeCompany[k][1].lower()+'.' in lstCompanyList[i].lower():
            lstCompanyList[i] = lstlstUniqeCompany[k][1]
```

---

[image]

I want to create a table as shown below. I want the output to be in accordance with the table below, where all the products related to the companies along with all its subsidiaries are shown in one column.

Comment: As an aside, if you don't particularly care which index you are at within the loop, looping over `range(len(somelist))` is better written simply as `for item in somelist`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. " but I need help writing the whole code." What is the **question**, exactly? What happens when you run this code? How is that different from what needs to happen? What's left to do, and what parts do you need help with? Please read [ask] and keep in mind that we expect **one** question at a time; if you have a complex task, focus on the difficult parts one at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question explicitly is how can I communicate in a CSV file, two columns containing several data, each separated by ;